# ACM Sigplan format authorinfo

Tags: acm

ACM Sigplan provides `\authorinfo` for author information. Currently, I have 4 authors. I would like to format in two lines each with two authors. However, by default, it formats in two lines, line 1 with three authors, and line 2 with one author in the middle. How can I change this?

```
\authorinfo{Author 1}
{Aff 1}
{email 1}
\authorinfo{Author 2}
{Aff 2}
{email 2}
\authorinfo{Author 3}
{Aff 3}
{email 3}
\authorinfo{Author 4}
{Aff 4}
{email 4}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `\@maketitle` to give the desired formatting in case of four authors:

```
\documentclass[preprint,10pt]{sigplanconf}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \begin{center}
  \@settitlebanner
  \let \thanks = \titlenote
  {\leftskip = 0pt plus 0.25\linewidth
   \rightskip = 0pt plus 0.25 \linewidth
   \parfillskip = 0pt
   \spaceskip = .7em
   \noindent \LARGE \bfseries \@titletext \par}
  \vskip 6pt
  \noindent \Large \@subtitletext \par
  \vskip 12pt
  \ifcase \@authorcount
    \@latex@error{No authors were specified for this paper}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{}\@titleauthors{iii}{iv}{}\or% HERE
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{vi}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{vi}%
                  \@titleauthors{vii}{}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{vi}%
                  \@titleauthors{vii}{viii}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{vi}%
                  \@titleauthors{vii}{viii}{ix}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{vi}%
                  \@titleauthors{vii}{viii}{ix}\@titleauthors{x}{}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{vi}%
                  \@titleauthors{vii}{viii}{ix}\@titleauthors{x}{xi}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{vi}%
                  \@titleauthors{vii}{viii}{ix}\@titleauthors{x}{xi}{xii}%
  \else
    \@latex@error{Cannot handle more than 12 authors}{}%
  \fi
  \vspace{1.75pc}
  \end{center}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}

\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}
\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}
\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}
\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

The change was made in the line marked `% HERE` which originally formats four authors using

```
\@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{}{}
```

that is, three authors in the first line and the fourth, in a separate line. The required formatting can be achieved by changing the above line to

```
\@titleauthors{i}{ii}{}\@titleauthors{iii}{iv}{}
```

or to

```
\@titleauthors{i}{}{ii}\@titleauthors{iii}{}{iv}
```

for larger separation between the authors (in my code I chose the first possibility, but you can use the one that suits you better).

[image]

For ecomony in the code, this can also be done by patching (using [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox), for example) the `\@maketitle` command:

```
\documentclass[preprint,10pt]{sigplanconf}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{}{}}{\@titleauthors{i}{ii}{}\@titleauthors{iii}{iv}{}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}

\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}
\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}
\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}
\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

To get bigger separation, one would use

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{}{}}{\@titleauthors{i}{}{ii}\@titleauthors{iii}{}{iv}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to learn better, which part is exactly is doing the formatting?

Comment: @nobeh I added some explanatory comment to my answer. I also added another option to do the same but with less code, using the `etoolbox` package.